# Is there a way to loop through database using a datacontext to find and replace a value?

Tags: c#, database, reflection, datacontext

I have a list of email addresses that give a bumb if you send something to them, so they don't exist anymore. There a a lot of them and it is unclear where they are in a huge database.

Is there a way to loop through the database, through a datacontext, not knowing the table name or column name, and still find and replace the value?

I already have a collection of table names and column names put together (if needed)

I have tried a bunch of stuff like using reflection and other things.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> tablesWithColumns = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var model = new System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributeMappingSource().GetModel(typeof(DataContext));

foreach (System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable modelTable in model.GetTables())
{
    string tableName = modelTable.TableName;
    tablesWithColumns.Add(tableName, new List<string>());
    foreach (var dataMember in modelTable.RowType.DataMembers)
    {
        string columnName = dataMember.MappedName;
        tablesWithColumns[tableName].Add(columnName);
    }
}
```

Is there a way of using the following (pseudo):

```
string emailAdresThatHasToBeNull = "gmail@someemail.com";
using (DataContext dataContext = new DataContext())
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> keyValuePair in tablesWithColumns)
    {
         string tableName = keyValuePair.Key;
         foreach (string columnName in keyValuePair.Value)
         {
              var list = dataContext.(tableName).Columns(c => c.name == columnName).All(v => v == emailAdresThatHasToBeNull);
              foreach (var entry in list)
              {
                   entry = null;
              }
         }
     }
     dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The wanted result is everywhere the email address was is now NULL.

Comment: You don't have access to the database? You do not know about which column in which table stores the emails?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Correct.

Comment: Is there anyway you can get that information?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya only through the dataContext.

Comment: If you have the collection of table names and column names put together its good to use simple ADO.NET to write update queries for each of the table and columns in it.

Comment: To me the bigger issue here is that you don't know how to connect to your database or its schema. ORMs are great tools for reducing development time and abstracting away menial database coding tasks, but they can't always take the place of a good database management software and knowing your schema. I would take a look at your database layout and find these problem values directly. If you don't know where your database is or how to connect to it, now's the time to learn.